# ushort array to Image object

Tags: c#

I have an array of ushort pixel data that I need to save as a jpeg file. From what I've found I can do this by using

```
Image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

but I don't know how to get the ushort data into the Image object. I've found ways to do this with byte arrays but not ushort. 
I've spent far to much time trying to figure this out so now I ask the mighty StackOverflow, How do I this?

Edit: 
 Sorry, the ushorts are 16 bit grayscale values.

Comment: It's not clear why your data is in a ushort (0-256 or 16-bit color depth).  I'll point to towards BitConverter as that may (or may not) contain your answer.

Comment: "array of ushort pixel data" means nothing alone.  What is the data format of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to actually create a `Bitmap`, draw the pixels onto it and save it afterwards.

Something like this:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(sizeX, sizeY, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale)

for (y = 0; ...)
for (x = 0; ...)
{
  bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color information from ushort array);
}

bitmap.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Note that I don't know how to get a 16 bit greyscale color information into the Color struct.

Comment: I agree, if you get raw pixel data (in whatever format) the most straight forward thing to do is create a Bitmap pixel by pixel.

Comment: This is great, but doesn't answer the question of how to get _ushort_ data into the Bitmap.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, and seems to work fine. However, just so you know jpeg doesn't support 16 bit grayscale so I'm using PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb and setting the r, g, and b to be the same value.

Comment: So you're effectively loosing 65536-256 greyscale values since R, G and B each are only 1 Byte in size?

Comment: yeah, but the jpeg I'm creating is for a thumbnail so the loss is acceptable. I tried using PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb so as to not have a loss of detail but was getting some odd result. Format24bppRgb is working so I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete working example based on the accepted answer:

```
 public static void SaveJpg(string fileName,int sizeX,int sizeY,ushort [] imData)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(sizeX, sizeY, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
        int count = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
            {
                bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(imData[count], imData[count], imData[count]));
                count++;
            }
        }
        bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use the Bitmap class, which inherits from Image.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) MSDN reference may assist.

Comment: This doesn't tell me how to get the ushort data into the Bitmap object.

Comment: I assumed that the Bitmap.SetPixel() was obvious.

Comment: Again, this doesn't tell me how to get the ushort data into the Bitmap Object. SetPixels requires a Color object not a ushort value. As my questions states I know how to build an Image (Bitmap is derived from Image), just not with ushort data.

Comment: @DanVogel:  How you determine what your ushort values map to what colors is up to you.  Do you want 0 to be black, or white, or red?  Up to you; but you have to put that into your code and use that conversion information to convert your ushorts to colors which you can put into your bitmap via setpixel.